# Issue with CSS drop down

Tags: html, css, navigation, drop-down-menu

Im having a little issue with the css drop down in my navigation. The products nav tab is suppose to have the drop down. Additionally, the nav works fine but it seems that the sub categories arent displaying correctly.

[HERE IS LINK](http://cawebdesign.com/demo/morgan2/)

Here is my navigation code:

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="home.html" id="nav-home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="company.html" id="nav-company">company</a></li>
        <li><a href="benefits.html" id="nav-benefits">benefits</a></li>
        <li><div id="nav-products2">Products</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="food.html" id="nav-food-serv">Food Processing Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="vehicle.html" id="nav-vehicle-serv">Vehicle Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="auto.html" id="nav-auto-serv">Automotive Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="laundry.html" id="nav-laundry-serv">Automotive Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="laboratories.html" id="nav-labs">laboratories</a></li>
        <li><a href="industries.html" id="nav-industries">industries</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" id="nav-contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
float:left;
width:1002px;
height:42px;
}
#navlist {
list-style: none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type: none;
}
#navlist li{
float:left;
}
#navlist li a {
display: block; 
height: 42px; 
overflow: hidden; 
background-position: top left; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;   
text-indent: -999em;
}
#navlist li a:hover {
background-position: bottom left;
}
#navlist li .current {background-position: bottom left;}

/* NAV SPECIFICS */
#nav-home {width: 129px; background-image: url(../images/nav/home.jpg);}
#nav-company {width: 161px; background-image: url(../images/nav/company.jpg);}
#nav-benefits {width: 133px; background-image: url(../images/nav/benefits.jpg);}
#nav-products {width: 112px; background-image: url(../images/nav/products.jpg);}
#nav-labs {width: 137px; background-image: url(../images/nav/laboratories.jpg);}
#nav-industries {width: 169px; background-image: url(../images/nav/industries.jpg);}
#nav-contact {width: 161px; background-image: url(../images/nav/contact.jpg);}

#nav-food-serv {width: 161px; background-image: url(../images/nav/sub.jpg);}
#nav-vehicle-serv {width: 161px; background-image: url(../images/nav/sub.jpg);}
#nav-auto-serv {width: 161px; background-image: url(../images/nav/nav/sub.jpg);}
#nav-laundry-serv {width: 161px; background-image: url(../images/nav/sub.jpg);}
#nav-products2 {width: 112px; background-image: url(../images   /nav/products.jpg);height: 42px; overflow: hidden; background-position: top left;   background-repeat: no-repeat;text-indent: -999em;}
#nav-products2:hover {background-position: bottom left;}

#navlist li ul { /* second-level lists */
position: absolute;
z-index:10;
list-style:none;
display: block;
background: #000;
width: 161px;
left: -999em; /* using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none isn't read by screen readers */
margin:0;
padding:0;
border-left:1px solid #a58545;
border-right:1px solid #a58545;
}
#navlist li ul li {
list-style:none;
display: block;
clear:left;
width:100%;
 }
#navlist li ul li a {
display:block;
overflow: hidden;
height:42px;
background-position: top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-indent: -999em;
margin:0;
background-color:0;
padding:0;
width: 161px;
 }
#navlist li ul li a:hover {
background-position: bottom left;
}
```

Comment: all tabs are suppose to link to other pages except the products tab. THats where the sub links come in. I think i have some of the code right but for some reason the sub links arent showing up

Answer (score 0):

With just css you will need target the `li` on hover, not the `div` in it.

And for the containing `ul` to show up, you will have to change it´s `left`.

Something like:

```
li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: you do not need a class or id to target it .. just use `#navlist li:hover ul`